# Removing the Logs in Java

Tags: java, logging, settings

I want To remove the logs which gets generated during runtime of code.

E.g i m using asterisk-java for voip/asterisk and I always got following messages

```
Jul 30, 2012 10:55:17 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl connect
INFO: Connecting to 192.168.0.27:5038
Jul 30, 2012 10:55:18 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
INFO: Connected via Asterisk Call Manager/1.1
Jul 30, 2012 10:55:18 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
WARNING: Unsupported protocol version 'Asterisk Call Manager/1.1'. Use at your own risk.
Jul 30, 2012 10:55:18 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl doLogin
INFO: Successfully logged in
Jul 30, 2012 10:55:22 AM org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl doLogin
INFO: Determined Asterisk version: Asterisk 1.0
```

Is there any configuration setting or other way around to remove the log and prevent it from generating while runtime of my code executions.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to remove the log file....remove the log file. If you don't want to print things out...then don't print them out.

Comment: It looks like you need to modify your logging setup so stuff like that won't get printed out. Are you using log4j?

Comment: no , with log4j i might get some custom messages that i specify .but i want nothing to appear is it possible

Comment: Yes. Don't log what you don't want to log.

Comment: @Jack Maney:- I have not printed these stuffs this stuff are printed because of a asterisk-java library i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved with help of mr srikanth yaradla.
I was needed to do the changes in the logging.properties file.which was not done by me earlier.

Answer (score 3):

By default Asterisk-Java uses java.util logging so you can have a look at the JDK documentation on how to configure it.

This link might help you.

[How do I disable the debug or "INFO" output from asterisk-java?](http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/faq.html)

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply change the log level by name/package?

```
Logger.getLogger(org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.class).setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Comment: it is showing  package rg.asteriskjava.manager.internal does not exist

Comment: Try using supplying it as String instead "rg.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl"

Comment: It doesnt seem to do anything i can  still see the same

Comment: Yeah, they be configured at a different level, try HashimR answer

Comment: Actually this answer is right, but package-class is "org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl.class" - its "org". I used Logger and Level from log4j.

Comment: @user2171669 Opps, copy and paste :P

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell if you are using log4j or jdk logging 
Googling on how to disable logs in  asterisk-java gave this 
http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/faq.html

Comment: i have gone through that but each time i came across that i can set my own custom message only for eg INFO: Connecting to 192.168.0.27:5038    i might do INFO:Loggin in

Comment: If you have not used log4j then have you tried disabling or even customizing the log levels for this package ex ( org.asteriskjava.level = SEVERE) in your JRE_HOME/lib/logging.properties   (you can explore other options as well)

Comment: Then are you sure you are not using log4j? is log4j.xml/properties part of  your classpath? or do you see this code anywhere in your project?`DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");`

Comment: i know u r first solution is the right one but it is just not helping me right now

Comment: Then are you sure you changed it in the right logging.properties file? Also try changing the ConsoleHandler level (`java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level`  and global `.level`) to SEVERE or OFF and restart your server and see what happens

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14613/discussion-between-azhar-alam-and-srikanth-yaradla)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like log4j???

im not sure what your requirement is.
but if you dont want to see any logs at runtime then write all you logs at INFO or DEBUG level
then change the logLevel to ERROR or FATAL in log4jProperties.

but just understand that the purpose of logs is to see them during run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to suppress output from the application, you could do

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream("stdout.log"));
System.setErr(new PrintStream("stderr.log"));
```

(Or create your own `PrintStream` subclass which just suppresses all output.)

Comment: Yep. They will cause the output to go to those two files instead of to the screen.